# Add popup to polylines dash-leaflet

Tags: python, leaflet, plotly-dash, react-leaflet, dash-leaflet

I would like to add popup to polylines in dash-leaflet, how can I do that?

In the example it is shown as

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash, html

#Simple-line.
polyline = dl.Polyline(positions=[[37.97168, 23.726464], [37.971687, 23.726464]])
patterns = [dict(offset='100%', repeat='0')]
arrow = dl.PolylineDecorator(children=polyline, patterns=patterns)

# Createapp.
app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(dl.Map([dl.TileLayer(), line],
                              zoom=4, center=(52.0, -11.0)),
                       style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run_server()
```

but, I have not seen a property that refers to add the popup value in the `dl.polyline`

Answer (score 0):

To add a tool tip in `dash-leaflet`, simply add a `Tooltip` component to the `children` property. Here is a small example,

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash, html

# Simple line.
positions = [[37, 23.726464], [38, 23.726464]]
tooltip = dl.Tooltip("I am a tooltip!")
polyline = dl.Polyline(positions=positions, children=tooltip)  # bind tooltip
patterns = [dict(offset='100%', repeat='0')]
arrow = dl.PolylineDecorator(children=polyline, patterns=patterns)

# Create app.
app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(dl.Map([dl.TileLayer(), arrow], zoom=8, center=(37.5, 23.726464)),
                      style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

[image]