# Trying to add on folium map to generate in a Dash App

Tags: python, leaflet, plotly-dash, folium

Trying to create a dash app that takes in latitude, longitude, and zoom, and outputs a map with a marker at the latitude and longitude coordinates.

The problem is that the map will not load and I think the error has to do with adding the marker, because the map loads and works fine with out the code containing the marker.

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import os
import folium 

app = Dash()  
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(id = 'textout'),
    folium.Map(id = "output-state"),
    dcc.Input(id = 'lat', value = 39.298, type = 'number'),
    dcc.Input(id = 'long', value = -76.590, type = 'number'),
    dcc.Input(id = 'zoom', value = 11, type = 'number'),
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-button')
])

@app.callback(Output('output-state', 'children'),
              Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),
              State('lat', 'value'),
              State('long', 'value'),
              State('zoom', 'value'))
def update_output(n_clicks, lat, long, zoom):
    if n_clicks is not None:
        m = folium.Map(location = ['lat', 'long'], zoom_start = 'zoom')
        folium.Marker(['lat', 'long'], popup = "You Are Here!!!").add_to(m)
        return m

@app.callback(Output('textout', 'children'),
              Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),
              State('lat', 'value'),
              State('long', 'value'),
              State('zoom', 'value'))
def update_text(n_clicks, lat, long, zoom):    
        return  'Lat {}, Long {},  zoom {}, number of clicks {} times'.format(lat, long, zoom, n_clicks)
```

Comment: You just need to put the passed in parameters (currently you have placeholders, eg. `'lat'` instead of `lat`, etc.) `m = folium.Map(location=[lat, long], zoom_start=zoom)`

Comment: Okay, I made the changes, but there sitll seems to be some error with it. When I go to run it in the terminal, the webpage says 'Error Loading Layout'

Comment: Ok then rephrase your question and include all the details. For troubleshooting, comment out all the callbacks and see if the layout loads, then - if no errors - enable one callback at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to using dash-leaflet. folium has some answers here. i tried it with folium but it didn't show the map. So i modified the code using a live riley that can handle leaflet in dash, i added dl.Map() as return value of submit and set the graph size, centre position, zoom value, plus tile layer and popup. The hints that led to this came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734674/add-popup-to-polylines-dash-leaflet).

```
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(id = 'textout'),
    html.Div(id='output-state'),
    dcc.Input(id = 'lat', value = 39.298, type = 'number'),
    dcc.Input(id = 'long', value = -76.590, type = 'number'),
    dcc.Input(id = 'zoom', value = 11, type = 'number'),
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-button')
])

@app.callback(Output('output-state', 'children'),
              Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),
              State('lat', 'value'),
              State('long', 'value'),
              State('zoom', 'value'))
def update_output(n_clicks, lat, long, zoom):
    if n_clicks is not None:
        return dl.Map([dl.TileLayer(),
                      dl.Marker(position=(lat, long),
                                children=[dl.Popup('You Are Here!!!')]
                                )],
                      style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px'},
                    center=[lat, long],
                    zoom=zoom)
 

@app.callback(Output('textout', 'children'),
              Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks'),
              State('lat', 'value'),
              State('long', 'value'),
              State('zoom', 'value'))
def update_text(n_clicks, lat, long, zoom):    
        return  'Lat {}, Long {},  zoom {}, number of clicks {} times'.format(lat, long, zoom, n_clicks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]